# GKE update calico-node-vertical-autoscaler image version

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, calico, linkerd

I am using GKE cluster with master version `1.15.9-gke.24` and linkerd2 as proxy for my `gRPC` services.

From my cluster I saw calico node vertical autoscaler pod is in `CrashLoopBackOff` state. From log I see following

```
$ kubectl logs -f calico-node-vertical-autoscaler-7767597775-rd68v -n kube-system
I0503 10:36:55.586271       1 autoscaler.go:46] Scaling namespace: kube-system, target: daemonset/calico-node
E0503 10:36:55.720025       1 autoscaler.go:49] unknown target kind: Tap
```

According to [this](https://github.com/linkerd/linkerd2/issues/3388#issuecomment-608169755) I need to update from `k8s.gcr.io/cpvpa-amd64:v0.8.1` to `k8s.gcr.io/cpvpa-amd64:v0.8.2`. I edited the deployment and replace the version. But it seems gke reset the image version to `v0.8.1`. How can I modify the version without uprading cluster?

Additional information:

```
    $ linkerd version
    Client version: stable-2.7.1
    Server version: stable-2.7.1
```

Answer (score 4):

> I edited the deployment and replace the version. But it seems gke reset the image version to v0.8.1. How can I modify the version without uprading cluster?

When you tried to edit the manifest to upgrade cpvpa image to 0.8.2 it got to 0.8.1 since GKE is a managed cluster, which is an intended behaviour.

- Any changes made to a `kube-system` object will be automatically reverted, this happens because the addon-manager will perform the necessary actions to preserve it state.
- Direct manipulation to these addons through apiserver is discouraged because addon-manager will bring them back to the original state.

**Upgrading the cluster Version once the release of 0.8.2 is available on the  [GKE Release Notes](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/release-notes) page is the only recommended way to get it.**

- As a workaround I suggest you try setting the `priorityClass` and `priorityClassName` configurations in Linkerd configuration as mentioned in the [Github Issue](https://github.com/linkerd/linkerd2/issues/3388#issuecomment-553486915) as the solution while 0.8.2 is not available.

If you need further help let me know in the comments!